# css missing symbol in web font

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I'm using a custom web font for my pages. This [one](http://www.fontspace.com/izabela-de-lima/bella-k-mad-font). I've opened the `tff` file to examine the characters, and it seems that only alphanumeric characters are supported.

My guess is that if a particular character is not supported, it will fall back to the rest of the font family. However, when rendering a `$` symbol on my browsers, it turned out to be like this.

[image: wrong rendering]

My css

```
body {
    font-family: 'madfont',"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
}
```

Why is the browser not rendering in Helvetica Neue or even san-serif the character `$`??

Comment: It seems that this font renders `$` as a star

Comment: @scrowler 4th character on the font's [character map](http://www.fontspace.com/izabela-de-lima/bella-k-mad-font/23634.charmap).

Comment: Yes, FuzzyTree is right. Go to the link provided for the font and you see in the specs the star for the `$`

Comment: Try different font for `$` :P

Comment: Sarcasm is hard to communicate online.

Comment: @scrowler tell me about it ;)

Comment: oh, why doesn't it shows up on the tff file??

Comment: @goh put a span around $ font and use arial as font family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken about the $ which you think is supported but it isn't, if you go to the fonts page, see the third image, which lists out all the characters... I don't see the $ anywhere...

[image]

To confirm this I also used customize option and yes, the $ throws me a *

[image]

So the best thing you can do here is, either change the font family, or wrap the $ in `span` element and use Arial as a font family for the span.